# jqgrid questions

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have following questions related to Jqgrid:

1) I have around 20 to 25 columns. How to make them fit within the page.

2) Is there any inbuilt functions for jqgrid for horizontal and vertical scrolling?

3) Also, when the value of the columns for each row is too big, how to wrap the text?

4) I have a column whose values are anchor tags. The JSON returns the value, but jqgrid does not display it. (Though it displays it on column hover)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do you want to squash the whole grid to fit all 20-25 columns on-screen, without a horizontal scroll bar?  Or is a horizontal scrollbar acceptable?  Maybe a better option is to make them optional: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns

2) Yup.  If you limit the height in any way ({height:"<integer value>"}) it'll add a vertical scrollbar when it's too long.  Unfortunately, it also fixes the grid *at* that height, so you may have wasted space.  {height:"auto"} will resize it to fit the contents.  Perhaps a more complete solution is to watch its size (not sure how off-hand) and set the height manually ( grid.jqGrid("setGridParam",{"height":"value"}) ) if it goes over a certain value.

Horizontal scrollbars in particular: as long as {shrinkToFit:} isn't true, when you specify column widths in the colModel you can make them larger than the grid's container.  That'll start a horizontal scrollbar.  If it's set to true, they'll be proportional values to make everything fit, not absolutes. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

3) I've been using this:

```
/* Headers: */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div,
/* Other cells: */
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td
{
    height:auto;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

4) The column labels are like `<a>title</a>`?  Not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Your solution for wrapping headers works well in FF, but in IE8, the columns wrap but the last sentence gets cut off and only half of it is visible. I tried using min-height:100% and height:100%, but they fail too. Any other suggestions?